# data with underscore in it is being selected rather than being excluded

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I hope someone could help me to clarify some doubts on this question.

I have got a table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entities` (
      `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `external_vendor_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I insert a record in this table:

```
INSERT INTO `entities` 
    (`id`, `external_vendor_id`) 
    VALUES 
    ('1', '64835_122334');
```

When I select a record with the following statement, then this record is selected, even though the `external_vendor_id` in the `WHERE` clause does not match the `external_vendor_id` that was inserted via the `INSERT` statement.

```
select id, external_vendor_id 
from `entities` 
where `external_vendor_id` = 64835;
```

This is happening on MySQL 5.7.12.

#### Questions

- Does anybody know if this is an expected result?  (if so why?)
- Or is this a bug in this MySQL version?

Any help will be much appreciated. And a modification of the query to avoid this result will be very helpful to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some form of implicit conversion happening in the background which is converting your input value `64835` to a `char` value that results in the record being selected.

This could be a bug, but could also be a feature. People with more internal knowledge on the workings of MySQL will be able to provide a better explanation.

What you can do is add single quotes to your statement to ensure you are passing on a `varchar` and not an `int` that is getting converted:

```
-- quoting "characters"
select id, external_vendor_id 
  from `entities` 
  where `external_vendor_id` = '64835';
```

You could also `cast` the value to a `char(5)`:

```
-- cast value to char(5) 
select id, external_vendor_id 
  from `entities` 
  where `external_vendor_id` = cast(64835 as char(5));
```

---

#### Full DB Fiddle w/ examples

Attached below the full db<>fiddle showing what happens in the various situations (incl. your initial findings).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entities` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `external_vendor_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
INSERT INTO `entities` 
  (`id`, `external_vendor_id`) 
  VALUES 
  ('1', '64835_122334');
```

```
select id, external_vendor_id 
  from `entities` 
  where `external_vendor_id` = 64835;
```

| id | external_vendor_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 64835_122334 |

```
-- cast value to char(5) 
select id, external_vendor_id 
  from `entities` 
  where `external_vendor_id` = cast(64835 as char(5));
```

| id | external_vendor_id |
| --- | --- |

```
-- quoting "text"
select id, external_vendor_id 
  from `entities` 
  where `external_vendor_id` = '64835';
```

| id | external_vendor_id |
| --- | --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LO5oRMnq)

---

#### Bug Reporting

If you feel this could be a bug, then head over to [MySQL | Report a Bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/) and enter the information you have already summarised in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You are mixing and matching Data Types here.
Data in a char field, being queried with a numeric [literal] value.

This forces MySQL to [wrongly] try and convert your char value into a number.
In doing so, it stops at the first, non-numeric character.

Always compare "like with like" Data Types:

```
select id, external_vendor_id 
from entities 
where external_vendor_id = '64835'
```

(This will return zero rows, of course).

Also, read up about [Type Conversions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) in the Manual: